# How to use sample weights in custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I use custom loss function in `keras`. Now, I want to use sample weights in `Keras`.

I've searched in google and some article suggest `model.fit(X,y,sample_weight= custom_weights)`

But I want to use sample weight directly in custom loss function. My custom loss function quite complex  and for some reason i need to process sample weight directly.

for example:

```
custom_weights = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

#my failed attempt
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred , custom_weights):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true) * custom_weights), axis=-1)
```

note: my real custom_loss_function is very complex. In this question, I use "MAE" as example  to simplify the problem so we can focus to answer "how to use sample weights in custom_loss_function "

how to do this task correctly ?